# Prove that a set of matrices is base.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I think I managed to prove it somehow. However I'm not sure my solution is fully viable because it uses matrices instead of vectors.

The principle I used is the same as vectors. I found a unique solution which is trivial.
I need to show that the given base is : $base\in M_{2,2}(\mathbb{R})$

$$B=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}
1 &2 \\ 
 0& 0
\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}
1 &0 \\ 
 2& 1
\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}
0 &1 \\ 
 1& 0
\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}
0 &0 \\ 
 0& 1
\end{pmatrix}\right\}$$

I've written it as a homogeneous system:
$$a\begin{pmatrix}
1 &2 \\ 
 0& 0
\end{pmatrix}+b\begin{pmatrix}
1 &0 \\ 
 2& 1
\end{pmatrix}+c\begin{pmatrix}
0 &1 \\ 
 1& 0
\end{pmatrix}+d\begin{pmatrix}
0 &0 \\ 
 0& 1
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
0 &0 \\ 
 0& 0
\end{pmatrix}$$

**Please forgive if I am taking shortcuts; I'm just not that good with $\LaTeX$ format(just want to make sure my way for solving it is valid, and that I didn't miss something).**

Then I get $a=b=c=d=0$ as a unique solution which is trivial, thus it is $\in M_{2,2}(\mathbb{R})$.

Am I done with the proof, or there is something else? Also I am not sure if it is conventional to do it with matrices.

Comment: You have just proved the family is free.

Comment: You've proved that they are linearly independent, but you need to show also that they span the space.  (Or that the dimension of the space is $4$.)